# Author's active directory ID through CAML (instead of numeric ID)

Tags: web-services, caml

I am querying a SharePoint list using CAML, and I am selecting the Author column:

```
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="Author" />
</ViewFields>
```

Which returns the authors in the following format:

> ows_Author="123;#John Doe"

How could I select the author's active directory ID (e.g. "jdoe") instead of this numeric ID? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CAML, you'd want to have something like this:

```
   <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name='Author' />
   </ViewFields>
   <QueryOptions>
      <ExpandUserField>True</ExpandUserField>
   </QueryOptions>
```

The key is the QueryOptions ExpandUserField portion. That will give you a string like: `2362;#Alton Brown,#US\abc123,#alton.brown@somedomain.com,#,#Alton Brown` which you can then break apart and get what you need.